# My Godot game has weird lighting effects?

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

I am a beginner to `Godot`, and I am trying to make a box like thing, but when I add directional light, it has these weird circular effects:

[image: sample image]

I tried experimenting with the settings for both the material and the direction lighting objects (I have 2) but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, it is [Color Banding](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/3d/3d_rendering_limitations.html#color-banding). So, you are going to need debanding (which you find it in project settings under `rendering/anti_aliasing/quality/use_debanding`).

Also, it seems the colors are not great... Using a `WorldEnvironment` node, try changing the `tonemap_mode` to anything other than linear, and you might also try color correction. See: [Environment and post-processing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/3d/environment_and_post_processing.html)

Using a [global illumination](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/3d/global_illumination/introduction_to_global_illumination.html) solution will also improve the quality of the light.

Comment: I tried all of this, but sadly nothing worked however after changing the debanding, it now looks a little different: https://imgur.com/a/zwpK69T

Comment: @Useer_1782 Are you running in GL_Compatibility? Do you get the same result in Forward+ and Mobile?

Comment: Im Not quite sure if im running in GL_Compatibility or how to check but running the same project in forward+ removes the circle effect. If i continue in forward+, can i still make a game that works on android?

Comment: @Useer_1782 You might, but Mobile should have better performance, and Compatibility will run in older devices.

Comment: Uh oh.. after re opening the same project in forward+, i see the circles again.